# If Craigslist can't verify my phone number, does that mean I can't post an ad?

Tags: craigslist

I've been trying to post an ad on CL, but I keep getting `Your phone number could not be verified. Please start over with another number` errors.

I've tried with three different numbers, using free email and non-free email addresses, and using different IP blocks.

Customer service has not responded to my inquiries.

Does this pretty much mean I can't post an ad on Craigslist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following allowed me to successfully create an ad:

1. Before doing anything, sign up for a new account using a non-free email.
2. That's it.